The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v5.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher
I have installed Visual Studio 2019 16.11.42:

I have .NET version : 5.0.408

When I want to create an ASP.NET Core Web API like this - but I get an error:


The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v5.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.

I also check "Use preview of the .NET SDK" from Tools Options Environment Preview Features, but it doesn't work.



You almost certainly just need to install a newer version of Visual Studio here. Why are you using VS 2019 when VS 2022 is available?

Do I need to install visual studio 2022

It works on VS2022, thanks @DavidG
